# How to use a value from one list in another list?

Tags: python, list, loops, parameterized

How would I iterate through the values in one list and use them in another?
Say I have a list called fruit and another list called jobs

```
fruit = ['apple','pear','banana']
jobs =['clean the fruit', 'cut the fruit', 'eat the fruit']
```

and I want where it says fruit to be the fruits from the list fruit.
So it would return
'clean the apple', 'clean the pear', 'clean the banana'

Comment: `[j.replace('fruit',f) for j,f in zip(jobs,fruit)]`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use:

```
fruits = ['apple','pear','banana']
jobs =['clean the fruit', 'cut the fruit', 'eat the fruit']

for job in jobs:
    for fruit in fruits:
        print(job.replace("fruit", fruit))
```

**Output**

```
clean the apple
clean the pear
clean the banana
cut the apple
cut the pear
cut the banana
eat the apple
eat the pear
eat the banana
```

Comment: Fixed @Barmar. Thanks!